# How does the velocity vary in the case below?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

Consider a cylinder of base area 'A' containing water of volume 'V'. Let a small pipe of cross sectional area 'a' be attached at the bottom of the cylinder. Then, how does the velocity 'v' of water flowing through the pipe vary? i.e, what would be the instantaneous velocity for a given volume of water.

I thought of this problem after looking at my water filter. I tried deriving a formula, but I was unable to. [image]

P. S This question is *not* my homework. I was merely intrigued by what I observed on a day to day basis.

Comment: Hi and welcome to physics.SE! Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Comment: Well, can you please tell me how to rephrase my question? This topic genuinely interested me and I did try finding a relation, but I was unable to understand all the factors that came into the equation. So I was hoping someone could help me with solving it.